# How to write if and elif statements outputs to a data frame?

Tags: python, input, output

I wrote a script that allows one to write a certain option and it will spit out a a number based on a formula. The way it works is that you can write answers in order to get the certain product that you want. How can the output be put into a dataframe automatically?

Here is the script:

#Regrades Portion of PnL

```
Date = input("Input the date of the regrade: ")
lots = float(input("Please input the number of lots in bbls: "))
Product = input("Input the product you are using: ")

if Product == "Blendstock-A":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS CBOB REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Blendstock-D":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS CBOB PRE'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Blendstock-F":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS RBOB REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Blendstock-H":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS RBOB PRE'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Blendstock-M":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS GAS REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Blendstock-V":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS GAS PRE'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Catgas":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS GAS REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Cbob Reg":
  print((df['GC CBOB REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "C5+":
  print((df['C5'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Gasoline for Export-U":
  print((df['BLEND STOCKS GAS REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Isooctane":
  print((df['Reformate'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Naphtha":
  print((df['GC Naphtha'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Naphtha Light":
  print((df['GC Naphtha Light'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "NC4":
  print((df['NTET NC4'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Raffinate":
  print((df['Raffinate'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Rbob Reg":
  print((df['GC RBOB REG'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Rbob Pre":
  print((df['GC RBOB PREM'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Reformate Light":
  print((df['GC REFORMATE LIGHT'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

elif Product == "Reformate":
  print((df['GC Reformate'][0]*lots*42)/(100))

else:
  print("Invalid operator")
```

Comment: Please [edit] and tag a language. [tag:Python] ??

Comment: Isn't "data frame" an R thing?

Comment: It's also a python thing

Comment: `... put into a dataframe automatically?` - into a specific *cel*? Make a new dataframe? add a row to an existing dataframe?

Comment: Search: `pandas change dataframe value site:stackoverflow.com`